# datagridview расчеты между столбцами

Tags: c#, winforms

После импорта в DataGridView провести расчеты между столбцами и вывести результат в последнюю ячейку. Как можно это оформить?  [image: Data]

И как пропустить пустую ячейку после которой идет ячейка с данными и продолжить расчет. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите хоть какой-то код. Что вы уже попробовали?

Comment: А почему вы это делаете после "импорта", а не до?

Comment: потому что CSV файл импортируемый это парсинг пдф файла если делать "до" то много рукоблудной писанины в экселе будет

Comment: @ЮркаПилюк, то есть вы просто запихиваете файл.csv как источник данных для DataGridView, без какой либо предварительной обработки, а потом уже, пытаетесь что то складывать, вычислять. Так не делают.

Comment: @Mirdin я ток учусь... вопрос, зачем обрабатывать? данные есть нужно лишь задать от какого к какому столбцу вести расчеты по формуле... или я еще читал о каких то коллекциях... можно коллекцией работать?

Comment: @ЮркаПилюк, Если кратко: "Не нужно закручивать стамеской шурупы" - DataGridView, это компонент для визуализации данных. Если более длинно, то полученные из стороннего (не доверенного источника) данные нужно отвалидировать, потом обработать (провести те самые вычисления) и только потом показывать пользователю вашей программы. Если все это возложить на интерфейс, то рано или поздно вы столкнетесь с проблемами, о двух из которых вы кстати и спрашиваете.

Comment: @Mirdin понял спасибо) ну значит будем укреплять знания а не сунуть пятачок куда попало)

Comment: если в DataGridView выводятся данные из DataTable, в DataTable есть вычислимые столбцы. -- DataColumn.Expression https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Основная, ИМХО, ваша ошибка в том что - DataGridView это все таки View, то есть компонент предназначенный для отображения данных, а не для проведения расчетов. С моей точки зрения вам надо добавить в свое приложение слой логики, приблизительно так:

```
public class SomethingData
{
    private List<SomthingRecord> _rec_list = new List<SomethingRecord>();

    public void LoadFromFile(string path)
    {
         /* 
            1. открываете свой файл
            2. читаете построчно
            3. выкидываете пустые строки
            4. создаете SomethingRecord - передав в конструктор очередную строку
            5. добавляете в _rec_lict созданный объект 
         */
    }

    public IEnumerable<SomethingRecord> Records
    {
         get { return _rec_list.AsReadOnly(); }
         private set {}
    }

}

public class SomethingRecord
{
    public SomethingRecord(string data)
    {
         //здесь парсим строку
    }

    //публичные поля с удобоваримыми названиями, соответствующими названиям столбцов
    ...

    public string CalculatedColumn
    { 
         get { //здесь проводите нужные вам вычисления }
         private set {} 
    }
}
```

И при открытии файла к DataGridView привязываете уже не сам файл, а создается объект SomethingData, запускается функция LoadFromFile(), и DataGridView привязывается к свойству Records созданного объекта.